# Response.Redirect() Turns Response.RedirectLocation NULL

Tags: asp.net

I have a group of Asp.Net applications that all share a common HttpModule that contains some code like this:

```
public class MyModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
    public void Init( HttpApplication context )
    {
        context.Error += new EventHandler( context_Error );
    }
    private void context_Error( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        var lastError = HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError();
        doSomeStuffWithError(lastError);
        var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
        var redirect = GetErrorRedirect(lastError);
        response.Redirect(redirect, true);
    }
}
```

This works totally fine for all of my applications except for one. In the case of the one that doesn't work correctly, response.Redirect(...) doesn't seem to work. Instead of the redirect I expect, Asp.Net is redirecting to its standard error page. I've checked the configuration of this application and don't see anything wrong or significantly different from the other applications.

While investigating this issue, I modified the error handler with one more line of code as follows:

```
private void context_Error( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    var lastError = HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError();
    doSomeStuffWithError(lastError);
    var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
    var redirect = GetErrorRedirect(lastError); 
    //setting a break point here, i've verified that 'redirect' has a value in all cases
    response.Redirect(redirect, true);

    var wtf = response.RedirectLocation;
    //inspecting the value of 'wtf' here shows that it is null for one application, but equal to 'redirect' in all others.

}
```

When I set a break point on 'wtf' I'm seeing some strange behavior. For applications that work, wtf contains the same value as redirect. However, for my app that isn't working, wtf is null.

Anyone have any ideas on what would cause wtf to be null in this way?

Comment: Shot in the dark: does the problem app handle App_UnhandledException in global.asax?

Comment: Please don't redirect users to another page in the event of an error because that's not what HTTP 3xx redirects are for. Instead return code 500 and a suitable error message without redirecting the user.

Comment: @dbaseman No, definitely not. And note, the breakpoint I set within the handler is always triggered. Dai, I more or less agree, however this is a legacy case.

Comment: @newbyca what about server.tranfer ?

Comment: The problem I have with using server.transfer is that the users would no longer have the error page URL which includes a case number. Those URLs are used for tracking in the issue management system. But yes, we might end up doing that if we can't fix the underlying issue :)

Comment: does passing false into the redirect change anything?

Comment: @DanielPowell Nope, same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The overload of `Response.Redirect` you are using will call `Response.End` and throw a `ThreadAbortException`.  It says so in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  So, the fact that "it works" in other applications is interesting as it should never execute `var wtf = response.RedirectLocation;`  During a debugging session, it is not surprising that it's null, either, as there is likely some reason that it allows to execute that line during debug.

In addition, it will of course execute the default error page if you have the `mode` set to On or RemoteOnly for the `<customErrors>` [setting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in Web.config unless you clear the error **before** redirecting.  This is by design.

If you need to execute additional code **after** you have already called `Response.Redirect`, pass `false` as the second parameter to avoid the `Response.End` call and [clear the error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.clearerror%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) using `HttpContext.Current.ClearError()`.

Based on your example, I would rewrite your HttpModule like so:

```
public class MyModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
    public void Init( HttpApplication context )
    {
        context.Error += new EventHandler( context_Error );
    }
    private void context_Error( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        var context = HttpContext.Current;
        var lastError = context.Server.GetLastError();

        doSomeStuffWithError(lastError);

        var response = context.Response;
        var redirect = GetErrorRedirect(lastError);

        context.ClearError();

        // pass true if execution must stop here
        response.Redirect(redirect, false);

        // do other stuff here if you pass false in redirect
    }
}
```

Comment: AHH, context.ClearError() did it! ... totally forgot about that. Yeah, I'm not sure what's going on with the ThreadAbort exception either ... perhaps its not actually thrown from the request thread? I mean, obviously that or its not being thrown at all. But I had actually tried assigning response.RedirectLocation directly without calling response.redirect() at one point and got the same results.

Anyway, I think calling ClearError() tricks asp.net into not running its default error handler in the case of my 'bad' app. So things are good. Thanks!